# How can I count distinct only the values in VARCHAR array?

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I have a VARCHAR column with arrays in it (string as a array) in Oracle sql dialect how can I count the distinct values in it?

for example I have the following rows

```
ID List 
1  ["351","364"]
2  ["364","351"]
3  ["364","951"]
4  ["951"]
```

I expected to count 3.

Comment: Please share your table output instead of a number, and provide your best coding attempt at this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're on a recent version of Oracle, you can use JSON functions to extract the elements of the arrays:

```
select t.id, j.value
from your_table t
outer apply json_table (t.list, '$[*]' columns (value path '$')) j
```

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 351 |
| 1 | 364 |
| 2 | 364 |
| 2 | 351 |
| 3 | 364 |
| 3 | 951 |
| 4 | 951 |

And then just count the distinct values:

```
select count(distinct j.value) as c
from your_table t
outer apply json_table (t.list, '$[*]' columns (value path '$')) j
```

| C |
| --- |
| 3 |